# How to enable ssl in Apache Nifi with digicert issued certificates?

Tags: ssl, apache-nifi, keystore, truststore

I have the following Digicert certificate and a private key with following names.

```
TrustedRoot.crt    DigicertCA.crt    star_example_co_in.crt   star_example_co_in_private.key
```

I have figured out that TrustedRoot.crt is root certificate, DigicertCA.crt is intermediate certificate and star_example_co_in.crt is the end entity certificate.
I am creating a keystore and trust store to configure in nifi.properties . But they are not working. I am not able to access the web ui.
This is my configuration.

```
nifi.web.https.host=nifi.example.co.in
nifi.web.https.port=8443
```

```
nifi.sensitive.props.key.protected=
nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm=NIFI_PBKDF2_AES_GCM_256
nifi.sensitive.props.additional.keys=

nifi.security.autoreload.enabled=false
nifi.security.autoreload.interval=10 secs
nifi.security.keystore=./ssl/keystore.jks
nifi.security.keystoreType=JKS
nifi.security.keystorePasswd=password
nifi.security.keyPasswd=password
nifi.security.truststore=./ssl/truststore.jks
nifi.security.truststoreType=JKS
nifi.security.truststorePasswd=password
nifi.security.user.authorizer=single-user-authorizer
nifi.security.allow.anonymous.authentication=false
nifi.security.user.login.identity.provider=single-user-provider
nifi.security.user.jws.key.rotation.period=PT1H
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.url=
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.certificate=
```

Rest of the fields I have left as default.

I have been trying to setup this for many hours. I am not sure if the issue is with the keystore and truststore I am creating or with the configuration.
I am hosting it on ec2 instance and nifi.example.co.in is mapped to this ec2-server. All the required port are opened on the ec2-server.
Please help me with this setup.